# How to set subprotocol with boost weboscket

Tags: websocket, beast-websockets

I want to use the subprotocol with boost websocket.

For example, I have s websocket server address , ws://127.0.0.1:5005.
Now I want to replace it with ws://127.0.0.1:5005/order.
"order" is the subprotocol in websocket, which could be used in libwebsocket.
I find no resource about subprotocol with boost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to set subprotocol for Websocket in Boost:

if the Boost version >= 1.7.0, then: [Click here for more detail](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_websocket/decorator.html)

```
stream<tcp_stream> ws(ioc);
ws.set_option(stream_base::decorator(
[](request_type& req)
{
    // Set the client field on the request
    req.set(boost::beast::http::field::sec_websocket_protocol, "protoo");
    req.set(boost::beast::http::field::sec_websocket_version, "13");
    req.set(boost::beast::http::field::sec_websocket_extensions,
            "xxx");
}));
```

else: [Click here for more detail](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_websocket/handshaking_clients.html)

```
stream<tcp_stream> ws(ioc);
ws.handshake_ex("ws://127.0.0.1:5005", "/",
[](request_type& req)
{
    req.insert(boost::beast::http::field::sec_websocket_protocol, "protoo");
    req.insert(boost::beast::http::field::sec_websocket_version, "13");
    req.insert(boost::beast::http::field::sec_websocket_extensions,
            "xxx");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`handshake` method takes a target (the subprotocol as you describe it) as an options parameter.

[Per documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_websocket/handshaking.html):

```
// Do the websocket handshake in the client role, on the connected stream.
// The implementation only uses the Host parameter to set the HTTP "Host" field,
// it does not perform any DNS lookup. That must be done first, as shown above.

ws.handshake(
    "www.example.com",  // The Host field
    "/order"            // The request-target
);
```